# Jquery addClass not adding class

Tags: html, jquery, css, css-transitions

I'm using jquery to add a class as part of a css transition but jquery is not adding the class even though everything else in the function is working.

I'm trying to add

```
<div id="brackContentVis" class="infoHide">
    <div class="Team1_Seed">
       <p>1</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the button that fires the function.

```
 <button_Top16_@season.Season class="btn btn-block text-left CardTitle 
 collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo_@season.Season" 
 aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
 <a href="#" id=@season.Season class="infoIcon" 
 onClick="Top16Results(this.id)"><i id="Top16_infoIcon_@season.Season" 
 class="fas fa-caret-square-down"></i></a>
 &nbsp;&nbsp; Top 16 Reseed &nbsp;&nbsp;
 <a href="#" class="infoIcon">
 <i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i>
 </a>
 </button_Top16_@season.Season>
```

Here is the jquery to do so.

```
function Top16Results(clicked_id) {
   season = clicked_id;

   var collapse = '#collapseTwo_' + season;
   var top16Results = '#Top16_infoIcon_' + season;
   var top16scrollTo = 'Top16_infoIcon_' + season;
   var season = 'Season_' + season;

   if ($(collapse).hasClass('show')) {
    $(top16Results).toggleClass('fa-rotate-180')
    scrollTo(season);
    console.log('BTN Click Successful')
   }

   else if ($(collapse).hasClass('collapsing')) {
    // DO nothing
   }

   else {
       $('#brackContentVis').addClass('infoAppear');
       scrollTo(top16scrollTo);
       $(top16Results).removeClass('fa-rotate-180');
   }
}
```

Here are the css classes.

```
.infoHide {
  opacity: 0.0;
}

.infoAppear {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

Comment: May you check if the `collapse` element is stuck at either `show` or `collapsing` class? That could be the reason it never falls to the last `else` block.

Comment: It does reach the else block. The addClass is not firing. I've verified with a simply console.log statement.

Comment: how is this class relevant? `.hasClass('show')`